# After updating to 20.10 firefox is nearly useless. Slow, crashes/exits

Tags: updates, firefox

Originally I was using 18.04 LTS.

I thought it would be good to update to GG (20.10) though I did briefly try FF (20.04).

As the install was done on an existing 18.04 version things remained the same for programs, book marks, etc.

Ok, now the crunch:
I **USE** Firefox **A LOT**.
When it loads, there are......  8 x 6 windows of FireFox and each of those have anywhere from one to **THIRTY** tabs loading.

Believe me:  **It worked!!**

I could use it, also run other tasks as well - though a VM was pushing it with the RAM.
But the entire machine worked.

Now, I am lucky if FireFox loads at all.  Let alone let me browse.

When it loads some of the window's tops are flashing.
A screen shot does not really show this.  (I tried)

All that has changed is the O/S from 18.04 and Firefox from (what ever it was) to 83.0

I don't want this to be a finger pointing exercise between Mozilla and Ubuntu.
I would prefer it is helpful to all.

What have I tried?
I've tried starting FireFox with all addons disabled.
Still happens.

I am going to try to remember to (next time) launch FireFox from a Terminal and pipe the output to a file to look for things.

The machine I am using has shown it is well up to being able to have this running.  I have had it working for a few years like this.

This post is (for now) to establish there is a problem.
I will post more information when I get it, rather than waiting to get it then post, as I feel there are a lot of people who have very similar problems and I want it known:  **You are not alone!**

Comment: "*This post is (for now) to establish there is a problem. I will post more information when I get it, rather than waiting to get it then post*" -- Please do not submit your question until you are able to provide enough information that someone might attempt to answer.  This is not a discussion forum or a place to make bug reports.  We don't need an extended narrative about how you *feel* about the problem -- if you'd like help with this we actually do need the documentation. Have you tried to ["refresh" firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings)?

Comment: This is an update.

Running Firefox from a terminal:

me@me-desktop:~/crashes$ firefox > log.txt
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Killed
me@me-desktop:~/crashes$

Comment: That does not answer my question.  Did you try to refresh firefox?  Please do not add text in comments that needs formatting.  Use the edit link below your question.  Commands and terminal output should be rendered in `monospace` font and line breaks need to be retained so we can parse the data correctly.  You will achieve a better response and will be more likely to find an answer if you take some time and compose your question right from the beginning.  It doesn't help anyone to post like this.  We aren't running out of spaces for new questions.

Comment: This "refresh Firefox"   That is where it basically strips itself back to .....  brand new and you lose all things like bookmarks, addons etc?

Thought:  Can you give me a site where I can ask questions?
I am finding things frustrating that I have to post a full bug report on something about which I know.... NOTHING.

I am a user.  Not a programmer.   I don't know how to create a "bug report" that is of any use to people.

So, rather than waste your - and my - time:  Can you suggest a better site I can use?

Comment: Nobody's asking you to make a bug report, and we don't take bug reports here anyway.  Read the documentation on what "Refresh" does in Firefox.  It will put your old settings in a folder.  If you have problems with Firefox, this is one of the first steps to fix it.  This will also let us know whether the problem is with Firefox itself, or some issue with Ubuntu.  We aren't asking you to be an expert, but for your own sake, you should try to document the problem in a way that people who are more knowledgeable might understand your problem.

Comment: At this point all I can "Document" is I updated the O/S.  FireFox updated too.
Now, just about every time I run FireFox: within 5 minutes it "crashes".
But there is no crash log.  Just what I posted....  Something about a channel error.
I can't give you more information as I don't have any.  I don't know how to get any more.  Doing what I read "firefox > filename.txt" to see the crash report.
Kind of difficult if filename.txt is empty.  Meanwhile I am trying something and if it makes FireFox stable, I will post the information here.

Comment: Please attempt to refresh firefox. Since this problem only affects firefox and might not actually be anything with Ubuntu itself. Refresh doesn't really delete anything so you can [import](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/recovering-important-data-from-an-old-profile) what was refreshed.  This is diagnostic step #1 if there is no obvious glaring issue.  There are too many possible reasons for firefox to misbehave- it is like searching for a needle in a haystack

Comment: Nmath,  I have done that and there is no real difference to how reliable firefox is.
This is one log I captured from firefox crashing  [link](https://pastebin.com/H2d7Zjhq)
And this is another log:  [link](https://pastebin.com/R1Fsz7Kp)
Maybe these can help determine where the problem is.